# Fail validation if text contains HTML

Tags: c#, html, fluentvalidation

Using FluentValidation I have a rule that looks like this:

```
RuleFor(x => x.CodeDescription).Matches(ValidatorUtility.Contains_Html_Regex)
    .WithMessage(EpisodeCodeDescription_Contains_HTML.ErrorMessage());
```

My `ValidatorUtility.Contains_Html_Regex` = `<[a-z][\s\S]*>`

This only fails if a description DOES NOT contain HTML (which is everything).

I want to do the opposite.  I want to fail validation if the description contains simple html `<html></b><asdf/>` etc

Is there a way to create a regex statement (or some other fluentValidation method) that will fail if a field CONTAINS html?

Comment: Please show us the value of `Contains_Html_Regex`.

Comment: @mjwills  `My ValidatorUtility.Contains_Html_Regex value is <[a-z][\s\S]*>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options.

1. Use [`When` or `Unless`](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Customising&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#WhenUnless).
2. Change your regex to [match a non match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318279/c-sharp-regex-to-match-a-string-that-doesnt-contain-a-certain-string).
3. Pass in a lambda.

   `RuleFor(x => x.CodeDescription)
   .Must(x=> !Regex.IsMatch(x, ValidatorUtility.Contains_Html_Regex));`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!