# Find any line that starts with this and doesn't contain that

Tags: c#, regex

How do I find any string that starts with `abc` and doesn't have the word `test` anywhere in the rest of the string?

```
abc blah test (no match)
abc blah blah test (no match)
abc blah (match)
```

I found the following but I don't know how to put in the `abc` part.

```
^(?!.*Test).*$
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1318314/139698

Comment: You can use `(?i)^abc(?!.*\bTest\b).*$` https://regex101.com/r/Y7zhR9/1

Comment: `var result = words.Where(word => word.StartsWith("abc") && word.Contains("test")).ToList();`

Comment: Wouldn't you just put `abc` after the start character (`'^'`)?

Comment: @RufusL `.Contains()` might be a good idea. I just want to point out that it won't work if the OP wants to reject "test" but not "testing", which is likely the case here.

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks, if you write that as an answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the match case insensitive using for example an inline modifier `(?i)` and use word boundaries `\b` around `test` and after `abc` to prevent partial matches.

Match abc first, and use the assertion afterwards.

```
(?i)^abc\b(?!.*\bTest\b).*$
```

[.Net regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fi%29%5eabc%5cb%28%3f!.*%5cbTest%5cb%29.*%24&i=abc+blah+test%0d%0aabc+blah+blah+test%0d%0aabc+blah&o=m)