# How to remove all columns whose column labels contain unique characters from Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe contains 3700 rows x 53 columns. I need to remove all columns which contains unique characters "nan" from this dataframe.

For example:

```
df = 

 X1  X2_nan      x3  x4_nan
 34       0    65.8       1
 35       1  5432.1       1
 87       1   443.1       0
 65       0   213.3       0
```

I want to remove all columns contains "nan" to get:

```
df1 = 

 X1      x3
 34    65.8
 35  5432.1
 87   443.1
 65   213.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for test substring `nan`s and filter by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `~` for invert mask for NOT contains:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.astype(str).str.contains('nan')]
print (df1)
   X1      x3
0  34    65.8
1  35  5432.1
2  87   443.1
3  65   213.3
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I got this error "Can only use .str accessor with string values!"

Comment: @Mohamed - Add `.astype(str)`, answer was edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.filter()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with regex, as follows:

The regex `^(?!.*nan).*$` is to match only strings that **does not contain** character sequence 'nan' anywhere in the column names.

```
df1 = df.filter(regex=r'^(?!.*nan).*$')



print (df1)
   X1      x3
0  34    65.8
1  35  5432.1
2  87   443.1
3  65   213.3
```

If you are not familiar with regex and want to make sure the regex is correct, you can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318279/c-sharp-regex-to-match-a-string-that-doesnt-contain-a-certain-string) for further information.